# Fans go to 100% during shutdown, Waiting for background programs to close

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, fan

After telling the computer to shutdown, the `Waiting for background programs to close.` screen pops up, but does not actually list any programs that it's waiting on.  The fans also kick up to full speed.

The computer also does not shutdown at all.  As far as I can tell, this only happens what a user is logged in.  From the `Welcome` screen, if you choose the `shutdown` option from the red button/box, the system does a complete shut-down with no problems.

I've already run Kaspersky's rescue disk and it found 3 viruses that are now quarantined, but the issue persists.

If the shutdown process is aborted, and then re-attempted, the computer does actually shutdown.

Where do I go from here?

System is Windows 7 Professional x64.

Comment: Does it do it for ANY user who logs into that computer?  Does it do it with all 3rd party start-up utilities and services disabled (MSConfig)? any 3rd party Explorer extensions installed?

Comment: What other security software have you used?  Anti-Virus software like Kaspersky is not design to find malware its normally only able to find infections considered in the "virus" category.  You say the computer does not shutdown, then you indicate, it does shutdown and without any problems.

Comment: @Ramhound It doesn't shutdown the first time through.  I have to actually cancel the shutdown and then re-attempt the shutdown process.  The second time through is when it actually shuts down.

Also, we use Sophos and that found no viruses, but does keep popping up security warnings about attempts to connect to a known virus site.

Comment: @techie007 It appears to be limited to a single user.  I did not try MSConfig yet, but I believe they do have Xplorer2 installed.

Comment: It sounds like when that user logs in, they have something that is starting up which hangs when that service tries to stop. Go through a process of elimination to determine the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You found viruses, so its possible there are corrupted files.  Run a [system file check](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) by running `SFC /scannow` from an administrator command prompt to see if there any damaged system files.  A [chkdsk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491051.aspx) would not be a bad idea either.

Comment: SFC came back clean, doing a chkdsk now.